# R Match two string columns between two different dataframes

Tags: r, if-statement, match

I have 'df1' with data that look like this:

| Object | Thing |
| --- | --- |
| apple tini | drink |
| vodka cran | beverage |
| tom collins | alcohol |
| arnie palmer | cocktail |

And I have 'df2' with data that look like this:

| Object1 | Thing1 |
| --- | --- |
| apple tini | drink |
| vodka cran | bever |
| tom collins | alc |
| arnie palmer | cocktail |

I am looking to check and see if Object and Thing from df1 match any Object1 and Thing1 from df2, and if they do match, a 1 is created in a new column in df1 and if they don't, a 0 is created, so that it looks like this:

| Object | Thing | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple tini | drink | 1 |
| vodka cran | beverage | 0 |
| tom collins | alc | 0 |
| arnie palmer | cocktail | 1 |

Note that columns are intentionally different in case they don't match is the actual dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an extra column and then left_joining solves this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- mutate(df2, Value = 1)

left_join(df1, df3, by=c("Object" = "Object1",
                         "Thing" = "Thing1")) %>%
  mutate(Value = replace_na(Value, 0))

#    Object    Thing Value
# 1    tini    drink     1
# 2    cran beverage     0
# 3 collins  alcohol     0
# 4  palmer cocktail     1
```

Comment: My dataset is quite large, so I could be missing something, but it seems to work just fine. Will update if I see any issues. Thank you very much!